# Non trivial morphism between ideal sheaf and structure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-singular projective variety. Let $I\subset O_X$ be an ideal sheaf corresponding to a closed subscheme of codimension $\geq 2$ in $X$. Is it possible to have a non-zero morphism

$$I\rightarrow O_X$$ which is not an inclusion? Suppose this is so, then we have an exact sequence where $K$ and $C$ are the kernel and cokernel respectively:

$$0\rightarrow K\rightarrow I\rightarrow O_X\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0.$$
Here $K$ should be of rank 1 if we assume that $I\rightarrow O_X$ is not inclusion.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any non-trivial automorphism of $X$ - i.e. $\operatorname{PGL}_n(k)$ for the special case $X=\mathbb P_k^n$ - gives of course rise to a map $I \to \mathcal O_X$ which is not the given inclusion. The kernel is still zero and the cokernel is $\mathcal O_{Z}$, where $Z$ is the image of the closed subscheme w.r.t. the automorphism.

Comment: @MooS, Thanks, can there be a non-injective, non-zero morphism from $I\rightarrow O_X$? That is why I wanted kernel $K$ to be rank 1. Maybe I will edit the question.

Comment: No this is not possible. Tensor your exact sequence with the function field and note that the first three terms have rank $1$. Thus the cokernel must have rank $1$, too. But it is torsion if the morphism is non-trivial...

Comment: @MooS, sorry this is a silly question. Why should the cokernel be torsion for a non-trivial morphism. Also if you comment an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: The co-kernel is annihilated by the image (which is a non-zero ideal sheaf). In particular it is zero at the generic point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize my comments into an answer: We have the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be an integral scheme and $I \subset \mathcal O_X$ a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals. Then any morphism $I \to \mathcal O_X$ is either trivial or injective.

**Proof.** Assume that the morphism is not injective, let $K$ be the kernel and $C$ the cokernel. $K$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-submodule of $I$, in particular it is again a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals. Furthermore it is non-zero, thus it is non-zero at the generic point $\eta \in X$. Hence we have $K_\eta = I_\eta = \mathcal O_{X,\eta} = k$ (function field of $X$). Consider the exact sequence
$$0 \to K \to I \to \mathcal O_{X,\eta} \to C \to 0$$ and pass to the stalk at $\eta$ to get an exact sequence
$$0 \to k \to k \to k \to C_\eta \to 0.$$
The alternating sum of dimensions is zero, thus $C_\eta = k$. Let $J \subset \mathcal O_X$ the image of the morphism, which is again a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals. We obtain $k=C_\eta = \mathcal O_{X,\eta}/J_\eta = k/J_\eta$, hence $J_\eta=0$ and thus $J=0$.

We have shown that any non-injective morphism is trivial, i.e. the desired statement.